# Transition of background-color

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a transition effect with `background-color` when hovering menu items, but it does not work. Here is my CSS code:

```css
#content #nav a:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color: #AD310B;
    /* Firefox */
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in;
    /* WebKit */
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in;
    /* Opera */
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in;
    /* Standard */
    transition: all 1s ease-in;
}
```

The `#nav` `div` is a menu `ul` list of items.

Answer (score 635):

As far as I know, transitions currently work in Safari, Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Internet Explorer 10+.

This should produce a fade effect for you in these browsers:

```css
a {
    background-color: #FF0;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: #AD310B;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
    transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
}
```

```html
<a>Navigation Link</a>
```

**Note:** As pointed out by Gerald in the comments, if you put the transition on the `a`, instead of on `a:hover` it will fade back to the original color when your mouse moves away from the link.

This might come in handy, too: [CSS Fundamentals: CSS 3 Transitions](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/css-fundamentals-css3-transitions--pre-10922)

ps.

As @gak [comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411306/transition-of-background-color#comment17485011_4413289)

You can also put in the transitions into `content #nav a` for **fading back to the original** when the user moves the mouse away from the link

Comment: You can also put in the transitions into `content #nav a` for fading back to the original when the user moves the mouse away from the link.

Comment: Fiddle with **hover** and **click** transitions at: [jsfiddle.net/K5Qyx](http://jsfiddle.net/K5Qyx/)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to put the `transition:` into the non-hover? I think that each time the user hovers, the transition is compiled..

Comment: for future users, vendor prefixes should not be used here

Comment: @Claudiu: I assume you mean "for future users who don't care about supporting legacy browsers"? Either way, vendor prefixes will always have  place in the world, whether or not to use them is completely out of the scope of this answer.

Comment: @ZaLiTHkA chrome under 26 and opera under 12 have virtually no users and including vendor prefixes now in this case should be discouraged as it makes the file bigger with no benefit.

Comment: CSS `transition` seemingly can't handle color of kind "linear-gradient" as can be tested [here](http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/uIemr). And btw, @Ilium's answer deserves to be marked as solution.

Answer (score 116):

To me, it is better to put the transition codes with the original/minimum selectors than with the :hover or any other additional selectors:

```css
#content #nav a {
    background-color: #FF0;
    
    -webkit-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
    transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
}

#content #nav a:hover {
    background-color: #AD310B;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <div id="nav">
        <a href="#link1">Link 1</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not that it's better or worse. It's just that if you specify the transition on the lement itself, it will be animated when the element gets hovered and when it get "un-hovered". While if you apply it to the :hover, you will have an animation when the mouse enters, but not when it leaves.

Comment: This solution is overall better. The transition effect would and should be expected to fade in on hover, and fade out on blur.

Answer (score 12):

Another way of accomplishing this is using `animation` which provides more control.

```
/* declaring the states of the animation to transition through */
/* optionally add other properties that will change here, or new states (50% etc) */
@keyframes onHoverAnimation {
    0% {
        background-color: #FF0;  
    }
    100% {
        background-color: #AD310B;
    }
}

#content #nav a {
    background-color: #FF0;
    
    /* only animation-duration here is required, rest are optional (also animation-name but it will be set on hover)*/
    animation-duration: 1s; /* same as transition duration */
    animation-timing-function: linear; /* kind of same as transition timing */
    animation-delay: 0ms; /* same as transition delay */
    animation-iteration-count: 1; /* set to 2 to make it run twice, or Infinite to run forever!*/
    animation-direction: normal; /* can be set to "alternate" to run animation, then run it backwards.*/
    animation-fill-mode: none; /* can be used to retain keyframe styling after animation, with "forwards" */
    animation-play-state: running; /* can be set dynamically to pause mid animation*/
    
    
}

#content #nav a:hover {
    /* animation wont run unless the element is given the name of the animation. This is set on hover */
    animation-name: onHoverAnimation;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set transition to a tag styles and change background in hover

```css
a {
    background-color: #FF0;
    transition: background-color 300ms linear;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 300ms linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color 300ms linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 300ms linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color 300ms linear;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: #AD310B;
}
```

```html
<a>Link</a>
```