# Moving background gradient

Tags: background, gradient, move

I have been searching all over the web and even trying to use the code of http://adcyoungguns.org/ but doesn't work at all.
I just want to reply back the moving gradient effect on my div, but to be honest i don't know how to do that in any case.
Do someone ever tried something similar or can just show me an example please?

Gazillion of thanks

Comment: Please provide your broken code so people can see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: I am actually developing my new version of the website, but i first need how to do that kind of menu! Since it would change the entire design. However i am so thrilled out to use that kind of menu since i like the effect of moving gradient. 
Anyway i was taking a deep look at the **adc** website and looks like it has different layers changing colors, but still don't know how to manage it.

Comment: Check out this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25554852/moving-gradient-bar-in-css/25554853#25554853

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this before, but I think I can point you towards the right direction.

It's most likely either a CSS transition or JQuery animation.  If it's a CSS transition, you're in luck, because those are pretty friendly to work with.

On that note, it seems someone has asked a similar question here:
[Transition of background-color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411306/css3-transition-of-background-color)