# Issue with css color transition delay

Tags: html, css

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Iwtyg

I'm working on this small project (see the CodePen) and, apart from many other things, trying to make the `div.artMain`text gradually appear after the div is resized, but for some reason the `transition: color 850ms` on line 48 is getting ignored.

Is something overriding it somewhere that I fail to see?

Any thoughts are much appreciated!

Comment: Which browser are you using? You may need to add browser specific CSS e.g. for Chrome -webkit-transition: color 850ms

Comment: It behaves the same in Chrome, Mozilla, IE11 and Opera

Answer (score 0):

Add this after line 48:

```
-webkit-transition: color 850ms;
-moz-transition: color 850ms;
-o-transition: color 850ms;
-ms-transition: color 850ms;
```

Make sure you use the starting dash '-'

Comment: I use transition without prefixes on lines 14 and 25 and it does work, so I don't think it's a browser issue.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411306/css3-transition-of-background-color

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

It seems that if the initial `display` property is set to `none` all the following CSS for the object is not applied. So instead I used minuscule height on line 44 to hide the div and after that transition started working.

Thanks for all the suggestions!