# Animate element background color onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to animate the background color of a div onclick but it's simply not changing it:

HTML

```
<div id="list2" onclick="changeCol();">
    color
</div>
```

CSS

`#list2{ width:200px; height:100px; border:1px solid #ccc; background-color:#ccc}`

JQuery/JS

```
function changeCol(){
    alert('foo'); // testing function called
    $("#list2").animate({
      backgroundColor: "#8bed7e"
    }, 500).animate({
      backgroundColor: "#ccc"
    }, 500);
}
```

Any ideas why? [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darrensw/qggyec4t/3/)

Comment: jquery animations only work on numeric values, you cannot use it for background color

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery animate backgroundColor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use CSS3 (will work for CSS3 supporting browsers only, unsupported browsers WILL change the color but without animation):

html:

```
<div id="list2">color</div>
```

css:

```
#list2{background:red;transition:0.5s ease;-moz-transition:0.5s ease;-webkit-transition:0.5s ease;}
#list2.clicked{background:blue;}
```

js:

```
$(function(){ 
    $('#list2').click(function(){ 
        $(this).toggleClass('clicked') 
    }) 
});
```

working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/18v8ofwn/1/

note that instead of CSS3 you can use the `jQuery UI` library (see **mour** answer), without a single change for your code (cross-browser solution).

hope that helps.

Comment: `:hover` isn't onclick behaviour

Comment: Ya, toggling class is the best way imho, keeping design logic in CSS. As a side note, this could be only CSS solution, but this shouldn't be used in this case of a DIV: http://jsfiddle.net/18v8ofwn/2/

Comment: nice, js-free solution, checkbox is a nice idea. +1

Answer (score 0):

check

http://jsfiddle.net/qggyec4t/16/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#list2").click(function () {
        alert('hii');
        $("#list2").animate({
            backgroundColor: 'red',
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [jquery-ui.js](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js) and [jquery-ui.css](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css) with your code. It will work perfectly fine.

Updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qggyec4t/18/)

```
function changeCol(){
    $("#list2").animate({
       backgroundColor: "#8bed7e"
    }, 500).animate({
        backgroundColor: "#ccc"
    }, 500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working code for what you're trying to do using [jquery-color-plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) as it says in the [Official jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color plugin is used). Property values are treated as a number of pixels unless otherwise specified. The units em and % can be specified where applicable.

```js
function changeCol() {
  $("#list2").animate({
    backgroundColor: "red"
  }, 500).animate({
    backgroundColor: "green"
  }, 500);
}
```

```css
#list2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color.plus-names-2.1.2.js"></script>
<div id="list2" onclick="changeCol()">
  color
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle Code Snippet Link](http://jsfiddle.net/cfx_404/qggyec4t/29/)

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue before. JQuery cannot animate background color, you need a plugin to do that.

Here's one that does it:

http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/ is another

Answer (score -1):

jQuery, by default, can't animate colors. I'm using the following plugin when I have to do such things:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/

You can also animate the background using CSS3 which performs really well (see: [Transition of background-color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411306/css3-transition-of-background-color))

Answer (score -1):

DO you have a color plugin? You can't animate background color without it.
You can find one here:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color