# Why is it that when using JQuery, when I hover, there's no smooth animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have the following in my script.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $( '.elementoBarra1').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).addClass('lineaBarraActive');
    },
    function(){
        $(this).removeClass('lineaBarraActive');
    }
  );

});
```

There is a change in color (based on the instructions I'm giving in the stylesheet), but there's no animation (or transition). It just passes binarily to the other color, there's no animation where it passes through all the colors in the middle in a short-lapse of time.

Why is this?

EDIT: Just tried fadeIn() and fadeOut() and they are working properly, they have a smooth animation. Why are addClass() and removeClass() not working properly?

Comment: Can you post your code in `jsfiddle`?

Comment: The website to create a JSFiddle is jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Without seeing the style definitions, it's impossible to say. This code alone won't do what you want.

Comment: `addClass` doesn't animate! If you have the "animation" in your CSS, you should post the relevant styles.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3 transition of background-color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411306/css3-transition-of-background-color)

Comment: What does your css animation code look like?

Comment: @Vohuman it does if there is a CSS `transition` defined on properties changed by the class.

Comment: You'd have to show us the relevant CSS.  What do you have a transition set for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addClass` and `removeClass` api of Jquery doesn't provide any animation. They are just meant for adding or removing class.

If you want to achieve animation, then you must add `transition` in the class you are adding.

There's no need for jQuery also. Just use `:hover` pseudo selector to achieve it

```
.elementoBarra1 {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s linear;
  -moz-transition: background-color 100ms linear;
  -o-transition: background-color 1s linear;
  -ms-transition: background-color 1s linear;
  transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
}

.elementoBarra1:hover {
   background-color: red;
   -webkit-transition: background-color 1s linear;
   -moz-transition: background-color 100ms linear;
   -o-transition: background-color 1s linear;
   -ms-transition: background-color 1s linear;
   transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/luliri/1/edit?html,css,output)**

Answer (score 1):

You can try [j Query Animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

```
$( "selector" ).animate({
width: "70%",
opacity: 0.4,
marginLeft: "0.6in",
fontSize: "3em",
borderWidth: "10px"
}, 1500 );
```

You can set css style as mentioned above so that you can get smooth animation.

eg program: [Fiddle Url](http://jsfiddle.net/vivek_aasaithambi/ga3wamdd/)