# How do I implement a changing backgroundcolour with Javascript/ AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I try to implement an changing backgroundcolour into a view of my Ionic-Application.

`(Ionic Version: 1.3.1 (ionic -v : 1.7.16, Angluar.js Version: 1.5.3)`

One view of that application has this 'changing backgroundcolour' implemented already, but this works just for a fixed amount of e.g. 5 values. Because it uses an Array which contains all rgba-Values for these specific values.

Now I want to use a different and not fixed amount of values.
So I can have a transfer parameter to a function which checkts this transfer  parameter. When the parameter is lower than a minimum, the backgroundcolour should change to `'rgba(123, 236, 245, 1.00)'` with an transition.
And when the parameter is higher than a maximum the backgroundcolour should
change to `'rgba(153, 0, 0, 1.00)'`. The minimum and maximum should be variable, too. Also an important fact is, that the difference of the minimum an maximum is not allways 5. Otherwise I could use my Array.

For this propose I tried
**document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(123, 236, 245, 1.00)';**
But I didn't find a way to implement a transition to it.

Another approach was to use a **CSS tansition** like in
[Transition of background-color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411306/css3-transition-of-background-color)
but I don't habe a specific time for the transition just an "end-value".

No I hope, that somebody can help me.

Here is the code of my Array:

```
.factory('Colourdata', function ColourdataFactory(Limitdata) {
var svc = this;

//default werte
svc.min = 50;
svc.max = 55;

var colours = new Array(5);

coloursDB [0] = 'rgba(123, 236, 245, 1.00)'; 
coloursDB [1] = 'rgba(123, 236, 245, 0.90)'; 
coloursDB [2] = '#ffffff';                
coloursDB [3] = 'rgba(153, 0, 0, 0.90)';
coloursDB [4] = 'rgba(153, 0, 0, 1.00)';


return {
  getColour: function (wert) {
    if (wert <= svc.min) {
      return colours[0];
    } else if (wert >= svc.max) {
      return colours[(svc.max - svc.min)];
    } else {
      return colours[wert - svc.min];
    }
  }
}
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please re-write the question with only the required details and code. Check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why can't you use a transition duration?

Comment: @Pugazh thank you, I hope, that the quetion is better now and thank you for editing

Comment: @gcampbell I thought that I don't need it for this problem. In fact it colould use one.

Comment: @AmeLives what about `document.body.style.transition = 'background-color 2s'` ?

Comment: I tried to use it but it chanes not the backgroundcolour.

Comment: @gcampbell When I debugg the `document.body.style.transition = 'rgba(153, 0, 0, 1.00) 2s'`, then the  `.transition` - part is `""`