# CSS Animation isn't working, maybe keyframes is the issue?

Tags: css

im trying to do an animation with CSS that makes text change color when you hover over it. Here is my code, im really not sure what my issue is here. Doesen't work in firefox or in chrome.

```
@keyframes swap {
from {background-color: black;}
to {background-color: purple;}
}

text.normText:hover {
animation-name: swap;
animation-duration: 2.5s;
}
```

The keyframes part doesen't highlight as a special word in Netbeans so maybe thats the issue?

Comment: why not a simple transition ?

Comment: Are you trying to change the text colour or background colour? Your question and code conflict each other.
As @TemaniAfif mentioned, a transition might be easier, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411306/transition-of-background-color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's for text color you need to use the `color` property instead of background-color. I also wouldn't even worry about using keyframes for something this simple.  I would do it like this.

```css
.text.normText {
  color: black;
  transition: color 2.5s;
}

.text.normText:hover {
  color: purple;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I agree, this is a better way to go about it, however your solution still did not work when i ran the code, the color did not change.

Comment: Can you show the HTML?  There has to be a specificity issue or a typo then.  I did notice in your example you didn't have a `.` before your `.text` class.

Comment: It was a typo! Thank you so much for your help!