# CSS Transition - why does my code not work?

Tags: css, css-transitions

Quite a simple one but I'm sure I'm doing something wrong; the following code doesn't work in either Chrome or Firefox (ie, it displays as would be expected without the transition property, with the element immediately switching from blue to red):

```css
.button {
  background-color: blue;
  transition: background-color, 5s, ease, 0s;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">Hello world</div>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transition of background-color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411306/transition-of-background-color)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transition` properties should not be separated with commas

```css
.button {
  background-color: blue;
  transition: background-color 5s ease;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">Hello world</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it'd probably be something simple and obvious, I just wasn't seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no commas in `transition: background-color, 5s, ease, 0s;`

```css
.button {
  background-color: blue;
  transition: background-color 5s ease 0s;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="button"> Hello world </div>
```