# button like a charging battery on hover using css or javascript

Tags: javascript, css, button, hover

I want to achieve a button that fills up like a battery. It will start with color red first then change to green on hover.

[image]

I know the fill up animation but the changing colors while filling up I cant achieve.

```css
.outer {
  margin: 50px;
}

.button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: green;
}

.button::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
}

.button:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: black;
  transition: color 0.6s ease-out;
  display: block;
}

.button:hover .text {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <button class="button">
    <span class="text">Click me</span>
    <span class="charging-animation"></span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add the code you tried to the question, even if it doesn't work?

Comment: I added the code now

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411306/transition-of-background-color) might help.

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  background: #2b2626;
}
.button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #55eb63;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  background: transparent;
  margin: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.text {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 40px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.button::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 186px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: background-color 0.5s, right 0.5s;
}
.button:hover::before {
  right: 0px;
  background-color: #55eb63;
}
```

```html
<div id="button" class="button" aria-role="button">
  <div class="text">BUTTON</div>
</div>
```

Hope my code can help you. It just used css transition on both background color and width.

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot. But can it be changed on hover if ever?

Comment: @gingg okay I'll edit it

Answer (score 0):

.button {background-color: red;}  .button::before {width: 0%; background-color: green;}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).